# sending Json object from Server side to the client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm quite new to JSON, I tried to search on the web regarding my question but couldn't find anything, maybe its because the terms are new for me.

My question: is there any way / function to wrap a JSON object in the server side (in this case it would be ASP.NET coding on C#) and to send it to the client side and to unwrap it there?

Comment: As far as I know, you need a client call to the server before the latter can send any data. How else would the server know what client would need what data on what time?

Comment: my program work as the client never send request to the server, or sending any sort of info to the server, the server push the data all the time

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET MVC you can return a JsonResult from your controller action, like this:

```
[HttpGet] // or [HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction() {
    var object = new MyObject();
    return Json(object);
}
```

and read from your client function, i.e. using jQuery, like this:

```
$('mySelector').on('click', function(e) { // 'click' is only an example...
    $.getJSON('MyController/MyAction', {}, function(res) {
        // res contains your JSON result
    }
});
```